# Count Letters in a File - Assembly

Tags: assembly

I have to make a program in Assembly Language for 8086 or 8088 processor. Where a given `.txt` file will have all its letters (from A to Z, not case sensitive) counted and later shown on screen. The amount of letters in the file cannot pass the size of a word (16bits or 65535).

in the end  i show on screen something like this:

```
A - 00010
B - 00359
C - 00353
```

Comment: Obviously homework.  Post how far you've gotten.

Comment: Write the code in C, compile it, and submit the compiler output. :-P

Comment: Cute and effective-ish ;)

Effective because it will show the assembler and you can learn from this.
'ish' because the output will still have calls to printf (for example).

Comment: Based in kevindtimm's feedback, I now suggest to compile the program, statically link it, then submit the disassembly of the whole program. I'm not held responsible if your marker flunks you with "tl;dr". :-P

Comment: O.o Hum.. Cool, that's a good Idea... code it C.. I just dont' know how to get the compiler output... But I'll try to find out. I use DevC++ to program. Do you have any idea how to get the Assembly out of it? Sorry for my awful english and txs for the help

Comment: Usually the compiler has the option to compile to .asm 
Visual Studio uses /Fa 
GCC (and other Unix style compilers) use  /s

Answer (score 9):

Here is a list of some things you will need to know how to do:

- read the name of a file from the command line
- open a file using operating system services
- read the contents of a file into memory
- inspect the value of each character in the file
- make a table of letters and corresponding count for each letter
- detect when you've reached the end of the file
- print text to the screen
- convert an integer to its string representation
- terminate and return to the OS with a success exit code